# Moving Exposed Views Filter into another region of the page

Tags: 7, views, theming

Is there any way to move the exposed filters of views into another region of the site? i.e. I want to have a Search functionality attached to the a view by exposing the "Search: Search Terms", but I want the search to reside to the right in the "Right Side Bar" region and not directly above or below the actual Views field display.

Or put another way: Is there a relatively straightforward method of replicating the Exposed Views Filter functionality of one View through another Block that resides on the same page? This way, the Block which would act as the filter "controller" would reside separately from the View on a different region of the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a module called 'Views Better expose filters' which allows you to create blocks from view exposed filters.

Project can be found at: http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters
or 
drush dl better_exposed_filters; drush en better_exposed_filters

There is also some excellent documentation at http://drupal.org/node/766974

Comment: Is there a way to do this grammatically?

Comment: I have Views Better expose filters but I can't see how to do this - any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Once the better_exposed_filters module is installed, edit you view. In the "advanced" section there is a "exposed form" section, here click on "Expose form in a block" and select "yes", then save the view. Now you can go to the block configutation page and add the new block where you want (there should be a new inactive block "exposed form: name of the view").

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any module. Edit the view > Advanced > Exposed form in block. Put: Yes.

You can now add the filter in Structure as a block.